# VLOOKUP gets the non intended value

Tags: excel

I am trying to implement a basic search with VLOOKUP here, but it returns the wrong value. How can I make sure it gets the value I need.

For example, I search for "CHICKEN WINGS", but it returns "CHERRY TOMATO". However there is a cell which contains "CHICKEN WINGS/TAVUK KANAT". Which is what I need to get from here.

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: You should include your formula and relevant data within this question, so that someone doesn't need to follow an external link to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add wild cards to the vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP("*" & B2 & "*",F2:G54,1,FALSE)
```

[image]